# How to add xcframework inside a plugin programmatically for CI?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have Flutter / iOS app and I want to add a flutter plugin that requires xcframework linking for iOS : https://github.com/CommandersAct/tcconsent-flutter-plugin

Is there a way to add a framework to a pod in a programmatical way ? like inside Podfile ? or xcodebuild command ? bash script ? ChatGPT didn't solve the problem :(

I know how to do it inside Xcode manually on my laptop (Clic on Pods > tc_consent_plugin > Under "Frameworks and Librairies" > + > Under "Pods Projects", select TCCore.xcframework > Add > "Do not Embed") but I cannot access Xcode in the CI (gitlab runner), and without adding the frameword TCCore.xcframeword to tc_consent_plugin, I got an issue :

"'TCCore/TCUser.h' file not found .../.pub-cache/git/tc-consent-plugin"

It is not possible that the flutter plugin needs to be modified so that it does not required manual xcframework linking.

Thank you for your help